# drush config:import "There are no changes to import." for "content" view

Tags: 8, drush, configuration

On a Drupal 8.7.14 system with Drush 9.7.2, I modified the "content" view and now want to roll it back to the previous version that was exported with `drush cex`.

Unfortunately, drupal does not roll it back to the previous state. `drush config:import` only says:

> There are no changes to import.

---

I did then delete the "content" view, and the import said:

> Operation create für views.view.content: "view" entity with ID "content" already exists.

To circumvent that, I created the view manually and tried to import the original configuration. Again, drupal thinks that:

> There are no changes to import.

Why is that?
What can I do to force Drupal to restore the original configuration?

Comment: Try clearing the cache and then immediately doing it from the UI instead of using Drush.  If Drush isn't working, always try to do the import/export from the UI to see if it is the whole site that's broken or just the Drush install.

Comment: If you export the single view config from the site, then diff it against the file in config/..., are they different?

Comment: Using the UI did reset it! Maybe I need to upgrade to drush 10 to fix the problem. Thanks, @PatrickKenny

Comment: Updating drush to v10 does not help.

Comment: @Clive: "drush cex" says: " The active configuration is identical to the configuration in the export directory"

Comment: A `drush cr` followed by a `drush cex` actually exports the changes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem's source was the configuration file that configured the database as cache on CLI, while using redis when served via http.

This caused all kind of confusion, since clearing the cache in the browser did not do that for CLI :/